# Reading Powershell Progress Bar Output in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a program that is calling a powershell script from an event handler. The powershell script is provided by a third party, and I do not have any control over it.

The powershell script uses the powershell progress bar. I need to read the progress of the powershell script, however because of the progress bar the System.Management.Automation namespaces do not consider this as output. Is it possible to read the value of the powershell progress bar from an external program?

> ```
> Process process = new Process();
> process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
> process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-noexit -file \"{0}\"", scriptFilePath);
>
> process.Start();
> ```

Comment: Is the script running as a standalone or within the Powershell ISE?  Also, do you need to know moment-by-moment the value, or do you only care when it has reached 100%?

Comment: moment by moment. I am currently starting it via the edit I have made in the above.

Comment: If you want some programmatic control over the Progress stream, don't start `powershell.exe`, use `System.Management.Automation` instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add an event handler for the `DataAdded` event to the [`Progress` stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psdatastreams.progress(v=vs.85).aspx) of your PowerShell instance:

```
using (PowerShell psinstance = PowerShell.Create())
{ 
    psinstance.AddScript(@"C:\3rd\party\script.ps1");
    psinstance.Streams.Progress.DataAdded += (sender,eventargs) => {
        PSDataCollection<ProgressRecord> progressRecords = (PSDataCollection<ProgressRecord>)sender;
        Console.WriteLine("Progress is {0} percent complete", progressRecords[eventargs.Index].PercentComplete);
    };
    psinstance.Invoke();
}
```

(you can of course substitute the lambda expression in my example with a delegate or a regular event handler should you want to)