# Getting Write-Progress -PercentComplete status from within C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Basically, my goal is to capture the progress of a Powershell script within my C# instance. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815221/7692463) which is related but it is not working (nothing in the output console). Here is my implementation using the suggestion in the accepted answer.

**TEST.ps1**

```
Write-Progress -Activity "Finding user" -CurrentOperation "TEST1" -PercentComplete 1
#Some task
Write-Progress -Activity "Finding user" -CurrentOperation "TEST2" -PercentComplete 2
#Some other task
Write-Progress -Activity "Finding user" -CurrentOperation "TEST3" -PercentComplete 3
#Some other task
...
```

**TEST.cs**

```
//creating PS instance
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

//creating a runspace
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

//Associating the runspace
ps.Runspace = runspace;

//creating the pipeline
Pipeline pipeline = ps.Runspace.CreatePipeline();
ps.Runspace.Open();

//Feeding the script to the pipeline
Command myCommand = new Command("TEST.ps1");
pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

ps.Streams.Progress.DataAdded += (sender, eventargs) => {
    PSDataCollection<ProgressRecord> progressRecords = (PSDataCollection<ProgressRecord>)sender;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Progress is {0} percent complete", progressRecords[eventargs.Index].PercentComplete);
};

// execute the script
results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

I have no problem running the script sucessfully, but the event associated to progress seems to never fire. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Try to use `PowerShell` object instead of creating `Pipeline` yourself.

Comment: @PetSerAl Added a solution, you led me there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PetSerAl for leading me towards the solution.

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.Streams.Progress.DataAdded += (sender, eventargs) =>
    {
        PSDataCollection<ProgressRecord> progressRecords = (PSDataCollection<ProgressRecord>)sender;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Progress is {0} percent complete", progressRecords[eventargs.Index].PercentComplete);
    };
    Command myCommand = new Command("TEST.ps1");
    ps.Commands.AddCommand(myCommand);

    // execute the script
    results = ps.Invoke();
}
```

Basically, using the `ps` object was the solution. My guess is that I wasn't registering my event on the right runspace. Invoking `ps` now create a local runspace which I successfully subscribed to.